# В квадратной матрице любого размера выставлять единицу по главной и побочной диагонали

Tags: c#

Есть двумерный массив arr,
который представляет собой квадратную матрицу.
Как сделать так, чтобы по главной и побочной диагонали этой матрицы выставлялись единицы?

```
int[,] arr = new int[y, x];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    arr[i, j] = 1;
                    
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужен вложенный цикл для прогулки по диагоналям.

```
var matrix = new int[10, 10];
for(int i=0; i<matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    matrix[i,i] = 1;
    matrix[i,matrix.GetLength(0) - 1 - i] = 1;
}
```